# Unicode in tty?

Tags: utf-8, tty

I have to view a log file on Debian server which is written in Persian by a third party software. Is this possible to have UTF-8 + Unicode support in tty? I'm looking for solutions based on emacs or entire tty.

Comment: _Which_ "tty" are you using? The regular Linux console? Xterm? Are you using it locally or ssh'ing from another computer?

Comment: Emacs out of the box is fully equipped to deal with UTF-8 since several versions back, if your environment has the fonts etc. to support it.

Comment: @grawity The regular Linux console, no XTerm, not even any X is installed in target machine, and yes/no I'm both ssh'ing to remote and using a keyboard and monitor attached to target machine.

Comment: @sorush-r: So that's two completely different things. dtbnguyen already gave you an answer regarding local console access. But when you use ssh, I'm sure you usually _do_ have a terminal like XTerm or PuTTY running on the **local** machine, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hacks for unicode terminal support such as unicode_start but they aren't perfect as indicated in the documentation.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/23610/how-to-enable-unicode-support-in-a-tty

Alternatively, apparently 'fbterm' supports Unicode and there are already packages for Debian. You could try that?

https://code.google.com/p/fbterm/

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=fbterm